# Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy a rest app on Google Cloud Platform. But I got the following error:

> Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy

I don't know how to solve this problem. I have changed the version and also get the same error with the new version.

**app.yaml**

```yaml
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config: 
  jdk: openjdk17.0.1
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

**Maven plugin**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <project>myprojectId</project>
        <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
        <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you checked that your gcloud CLI is updated? YOu could check by running the following command: `gcloud components update`

Comment: when i enter that commant it return "All components are up to date."

Comment: Have you tried using version `2.4.0`, as in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only#prerequisites)?

Could you please edit your question and share the code you're using to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Additionally, could you please share the full error log, since the error you're sharing is too generic to troubleshoot your issue.